# Solution to the geometric progression starting from an arbitrary index?

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

We know that:

$$
\sum_{n=0}^{n-1}r^n = \frac{r^n -1}{r-1}
$$

What about when the starting index is an arbitrary $n_0$? Is the following correct?:

$$
\sum_{n=n_0}^{n-1}r^n = \sum_{n=0}^{n-1}r^{n+n_0} = \sum_{n=0}^{n-1}r^{n}r^{n_0} = r^{n_0}\sum_{n=0}^{n-1}r^{n} = r^{n_0}\left(\frac{r^n -1}{r-1}\right)
$$

I can't find any explicit solution to this.

Comment: @GitGud I mean if this is correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using $$
\sum_{n=0}^{n-1}r^n = \frac{r^n -1}{r-1}$$

Try computing

$$
\begin{align} \sum_{n_0}^{n-1}r^n \quad 
& = \sum_{n= 0}^{n-1}r^{n} - \sum_{n=0}^{n_0-1}r^{n} \\ \\
& = \frac{r^n -1}{r-1} - \frac{r^{n_0} - 1}{r-1} \\ \\ 
& = \frac{r^n - r^{n_0}}{r-1} \\ \\
& = r^{n_0}\left(\frac{r^{n - n_0}-1}{r-1}\right)
\end{align}
$$

Comment: It would be $\frac{a^n-a^{n_0}}{a-1}$, do you agree?

Comment: Yes, indeed, if a = r

Comment: Does this make sense?

Comment: Yup! You got it. Either the last line is fine, or the second to last line!

Comment: Nice Amy, I like this way

Answer (score 1):

I think this step is wrong $$\sum_{n=n_0}^{n-1}r^n = \sum_{n=0}^{n-1}r^{n+n_0}$$

Comment: You think that the index "shifting" is wrong?

Comment: You have shifted the bottom, but not the top!

Comment: yes.I think it need some modification.

Answer (score 1):

Let $n-n_o=m$. Then 
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=n_o}^{n} r^k
=
&
\big(
r^{n_o}+r^{n_o+1}+r^{n_o+2}+\ldots +r^{n-1}+r^{n}
\big)
\\
=
&
\big(
r^{n_o}+r^{n_o+1}+r^{n_o+2}+\ldots +r^{n_o+m-1}+r^{n_o+m}
\big)
\\
=
&
\big(
r^{n_o}\cdot 1+r^{n_o}\cdot r^1+r^{n_o}\cdot r^2+\ldots +r^{n_o}\cdot r^{+m-1}+r^{n_o}\cdot r^m
\big)
\\
=
&
r^{n_o}\big( 1+ r^1+r^2+\ldots +r^{n-n_o-1}+r^{n-n_o}\big)
\\
=
&
r^{n_o}\cdot \sum_{k=0}^{n-n_o}r^k
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

Here is an easy way to remember the sum formula. The sum of a geometric series is $${{\rm first} - {\rm blast}\over 1 - {\rm common\ ratio}},$$
where ``blast'' is the term that is one beyond the last.  This works no matter where the sum begins or ends.  If the common ratio has absolute value less than one and you are summing to $\infty$, then the blast term is $0$.

Comment: Amazing tip! Thanks!